# Problems inputting a variable because of the way compiler reads code

Tags: c++

I'm new here. Here is a piece of code in C++

```
int main()
{
    cout<<"?";
    int a;
    cout<<"?";
    cout<<"Enter no: ";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"?";
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        while(i>0)
        i=i/2;
    cout<<"?";
}
```

In this code, the nested for-while loop is basically an infinite loop. The code should ideally print 2 question marks... ask for input... input... print 1 question mark... and enter the infinite loop. But, nothing happens after asking for input. That may be because the compiler reads the code in some different order that I'm not aware of... Is that what is happening. What is happening?

Comment: are you sure it's not just hidden in the life after input? and what compiler are you using?

Comment: `for (;;);` is idiomatic infinite loop. Yours is just weird!

Answer (score 2):

It's because cout is a buffered ostream ... which means you need to flush it for the 'second' question mark to appear:

```
int main()
{
    cout<<"?";
    int a;
    cout<<"?";
    cout<<"Enter no: ";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"?";
    cout.flush();
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        while(i>0)
        i=i/2;
    cout<<"?";
}
```

### Complete aside on the nested loops

Also your nested loops are whacky ... WHAT are you trying to do?

Comment: I had to put j in the second loop. I put i by mistake! But got caught up with this thing before I noticed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::cout.flush();
```

Seems to do the trick for me.  It appears as though the stream is not being flushed before entering the loop.